# Using IPS and IDS together for Defense in Depth

Tags: networking, security

With in-depth knowledge of IPS and IDS, how can we use them simultaneously to achieve better security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so much that IDS and IPS duplicate each other; they're actually different functions. [This article](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/Do-you-need-an-IDS-or-IPS-or-both) summarizes IDS as "visibility" and IPS as "control."

If you want to actively guard people from threats on the Internet, you need an Intrusion Protection System. IPSes are always set up in a place where all untrusted traffic passes through them. Therefore, they can pass on the OK stuff and stop the bad stuff.

If you want to analyze, pick apart, summarize, or otherwise get insight into the traffic on your network, you need an Intrustion Detection System. IDSes don't have to be in a position to intercept traffic; they can be passive listeners because they don't stop anything, just log it. Note that some IDS functions now come with major IPS products.

Therefore, one might use an IPS to block known exploits and an IDS to see what's happening on your network. You might use the information from the IDS to identify a network problem configure your active security devices.